# Display WooCommerce Estimate Delivery shipping info in orders and emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to create an Estimate Delivery Per Shipping Zone in Cart, Checkout, Thank you page, and Email for Woocommerce.

I am using [WooCommerce Shipping Estimate](https://www.skyverge.com/product/woocommerce-shipping-estimates/) free plugin which works great displaying in cart and checkout the estimated delivery time.

Now the plugin doesn't display that on orders and  and email notifications…

I tried to hack the plugin and add a function hooked in `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text` without success so far.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LoicTheAztec actually, I am following your code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747221/display-a-custom-message-based-on-customer-shipping-zone-in-woocommerce

But whenever I try to add 

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text' , 'shipping_zone_targeted_postcodes_custom_notice' );

it doesn't display on thank you page, not sure what to do next.

Comment: I have tried the plugin and found the way to display the "Delivery estimate" in the orders and emails notifications on total rows after the shipping total. See My answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the plugin [WooCommerce Shipping Estimate](https://www.skyverge.com/product/woocommerce-shipping-estimates/) it's possible to to display the "Delivery estimate" in the orders and emails notifications on total rows after the shipping total as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'delivery_estimate_as_order_item_total_row', 10, 3 );
function delivery_estimate_as_order_item_total_row( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $from   = get_option('wc_shipping_method_estimate_from');
    $to     = get_option('wc_shipping_method_estimate_to');
    $format = get_option('wc_shipping_estimate_format');

    $shipping_methods = $order->get_shipping_methods();
    $shipping_method  = reset($shipping_methods);
    $instance_id      = $shipping_method->get_instance_id();

    $from = isset($from[$instance_id]) ? $from[$instance_id] : '';
    $to   = isset($to[$instance_id])   ? $to[$instance_id]   : '';

    if ( isset($total_rows['shipping']) && ( $from || $to ) ) {
        if ( $from ) {
            $from_days = _n( 'day', 'days', $from, 'woocommerce' );
        }

        if ( $to ) {
            $to_days   = _n( 'day', 'days', $to, 'woocommerce' );
        }

        if ( $format === 'days' ) {

            if ( $from && $to && $from != $to ) {
                $delivery_estimate_value = sprintf( '%d - %d %s', $from, $to, $to_days );
            } elseif ( $from && ! $to ) {
                $delivery_estimate_value = sprintf( __('At least %d %s', 'woocommerce' ), $from, $from_days );
            } else {
                $delivery_estimate_value = sprintf( __('Up to %d %s', 'woocommerce' ), $to, $to_days );
            }
        } else {

            $order_date = $order->get_date_created()->date_i18n('Y-m-d'); // Get Order date

            print_pr($order_date);

            if ( $from ) {
                $from_date = date_i18n( 'F d', strtotime($order_date) + ( $from * 24 * 3600 ) );
            }

            if ( $to ) {
                $to_date   = date_i18n( 'F d', strtotime($order_date) + ( $to * 24 * 3600 ) );
            }

            if ( $from && $to && $from != $to ) {
                $delivery_estimate_value = sprintf( '%s - %s', $from_date, $to_date );
            } elseif ( $from && ! $to ) {
                $delivery_estimate_value = sprintf( __('On or after %s', 'woocommerce' ), $from_date );
            } else {
                $delivery_estimate_value = sprintf( __('By %s', 'woocommerce' ), $to_date );
            }
        }

        $new_total_rows = array(); // Initializing

        // Loop through order total rows
        foreach( $total_rows as $key => $values ) {
            $new_total_rows[$key] = $values;

            // Inserting Delivery estimate array
            if( $key === 'shipping' ) {
                $new_total_rows['estimate'] = array(
                    'label' => __("Delivery estimate", "woocommerce"),
                    'value' => esc_html( $delivery_estimate_value )
                );
            }
        }
        return $new_total_rows;
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I am doing it wrong the entire time :D It really works!